# Saving current directory (using os.cwd) to a TCP server Python

Tags: python, tcp, concurrency, cd

I am trying to build a concurrent TCP server that can accept the command "cd" (change directory) to browse around different directories/files similar to Unix. Eventually I will add the ability to download a file from one of these directories you can "cd" to.

I successfully have a client send the directory in a command line argument, and the server successfully receives it. However, when I try to change the directory of the server, the server reset's its directory every time. In other words, the server does not save its new directory location and just resets back to default (where the file is located). Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
def changeDir(D):
    os.chdir(D)

def currentDir():
    return os.getcwd()


def handler(clientsocket, clientaddr):  #child process
    print "Accepted connection from: ", clientaddr
    while 1:
        data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
        if data:
            if data == "BYE":
                print "recvd BYE"
                clientsocket.send("BYE")
                clientsocket.close()
            elif data == "DIR":
                print "recvd DIR"
                DIR = currentDir()
                clientsocket.send(DIR)
                print DIR
            elif data.find("CD:") == 0:
                print "recvd CD"

                DIR = data[3:] #Stores the rest of data (user types 'cd:' then directory)

                changeDir(DIR)

#               os.chdir(DIR)
                msg = currentDir()
                clientsocket.send(msg)

            print "ending"

            return
```

edit: I should mention this is a concurrent server using processes and the rest of my code is down here

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
    TCP_PORT = 5004
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

    print 'socket()'
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    print 'bind()'
    s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

#    f = open('recv.txt', 'wb')

    print 'listen()'
    s.listen(5)

    workerProcesses =[]

    while 1:
        print "Server is listening for connections\n"
        clientsocket, clientaddr = s.accept()
        p = Process(target=handler, args = (clientsocket, clientaddr))
        p.start()
        workerProcesses.append(p)

    serversocket.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your application only has one single 'cwd' - maybe you should have a variable for each session which remembers the cwd for that session and applies it to all the client's requests?

Comment: This is a great alternative, I wasn't sure if it was possible to do without storing it elsewhere.

Comment: My approach to the problem was flawed. I was using command line arguments and instead I should have been using a loop with raw_input. Doing so solves my above problem. (Just in case you were wondering)